# Panning with Shift + middle mouse button stopped working

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

When I pan with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd>, it doesn't work. I think I might have accidentally pressed some sort of key-shortcut. It works for other views, so it's not my mouse. What sort of shortcut could I have pressed?

Comment: If you say that it "works for other views", do you mean other views of the same Blender instance?

Also, panning works with Shift + MMB, not Ctrl + MMB.

Comment: If the problem is only for one 3D View space, and it's in perspective mode, this might help: [Why does the zoom sometimes stop at a point?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/651/185). That's because you said the shortcut is Ctrl+MMB which is for zooming.

Comment: Did mean shift+mmb and edited post to clear of further confusion :)
Works for other 3D view spaces in the same blender instance yes.
I tried reloading Factory Defaults as dukejib suggested and it fixed the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Somehow, unbeknownst to me, I had locked my view (Shift-Numpad .). I had to unlock it again (Alt-Numpad .) before Shift-MMB would work again.

Comment: Don't know why, but I had to "Toggle Local View" and it worked again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure of the Shortcut. but you can get your original settings back by loading Factory Defaults. 
Its in File Menu.

The reason why it happened is because the user set clip start on view settings too low. If they use your factory reset method they will potentially lose work. Just set the clip start to 30cm

Comment: Be careful to load Factory Defaults as it will reset the scene to the good old cube, erasing all your current work (if you did not save it)!!!

Answer (score 36):

I've had this happen a few times to me, and not pressed anything I shouldn't.

I found going to object mode and pressing the home key fixes it. (View All).

I seem to get this problem when I've zoomed in too close, or am using the UV view.

Comment: I want to upvote this answer more than others. It’s unfair that I can’t. An underrated question following this answer specifically: [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69823/how-can-i-prevent-the-occasional-zoom-in-panning-from-breaking).

Comment: As a reminder, you can just hit spacebar and type View all.

Comment: This is dumb that this fixed it, because it seems like it has nothing to do with the shift / ctrl middle mouse movement. But it fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Six years years later and on Blender 3.0 I had a similar problem. Only for me it was very slow to drag but it still worked. Pressing the Home key reset whatever it was that was caused Shift + middle mouse to slow down to a crawl.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

If reloading the factory settings in File>>Load Factory Settings helps, then you can check your mouse settings in the user preferences, input tab:

[image: change rotate and pan]

In the example, the checkboxes are set to pan with <kbd>MMB</kbd> and rotate with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>MMB</kbd>.

If that's not the reason, it might be that you are in perspective mode and you have zoomed in a lot. Does the 3d view display 'Persp' in the top left corner? <kbd>NUMPAD</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> or holding <kbd>NUMPAD</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> will repair that.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and this solution worked:

- Hit <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view to open the Properties region.
- In the View submenu, turn off *Lock to Cursor* or *Lock to Object*.

It's not unlikely that a relatively inexperienced user would not realize that this setting exists, or would not know how to restore it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in Blender 3.0. Going in `Object Mode` then `View` and then `Frame All` fixed this issue.

[image]

Comment: This actually helped me, thank you stranger

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem.

Zoom (ctrl/mmb) and Pan (shift/mmb) just stopped working for one of my Blender files (but the rest were fine).

The simplest solution I found online was to hit the "period" key on the number pad.

Worked like a charm.

No need to reset to factory defaults or do anything complicated.

Just hit "." on your number pad.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by setting the daemon program "X Neural Switcher", well who would have thought!

Xubuntu 14.04: stop the daemon of "X Neural Switcher".

Answer (score 1):

I landed here when I could not find a solution. My 3d viewport allowed me to rotate around the object but panning was not possible anymore (and it worked before in the same scene).

None of the answers here worked for me. I found a simple solution for my case:

1. add another view panel (or select an existing one around in the UI)
2. change the type to Viewport 3D
3. after that, remove/collapse the previous buggy 3D viewport panel

It seems forces Blender to create a new 3D viewport that doesn't have this problem. Everything went back to normal, panning included.