# How to pan the view?

Tags: interface

How to pan the view in Blender?

Suppose neither <kbd>Shift</kbd>
<kbd>[image: MMB]</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> do not work. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Do other navigation controls (zoom, orbit) work in the 3D View?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2326/599

Comment: It is nearly impossible to find out which of the many possible problems that could be causing this without a .blend.

Comment: try reseting your preferences on FIle->Load_Factory_Settings.

Comment: AFAIK `Shift Alt LMB` isn't supposed to do anything.

Comment: For MacBook users, seems holding shift with 2 fingers on the trackpad pans.

Comment: I was also having this issue while editing a curve. It seems that you must be in object mode to pan.

Answer (score 11):

Unless you have changed your mouse settings, you use the middle mouse button to move in the 3D view, not LMB. Middle mouse to orbit, shift -> middle mouse to pan, and ctrl -> middle mouse to zoom.

Comment: There was some confusion when editing the question.. The [original](http://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/13432/1) says `MMB` wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 6</kbd> (arrows) in the number pad to pan left and right.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 8</kbd> (arrows) in the number pad to pan up and down.

If number pad is not present, Navigate to File -> User Preferences -> Input -> Emulate Numpad.

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you