# How to stop Blender from slowing down zooming and panning?

Tags: units

I am working with Unreal Engine so I have entered unit scale of 0.01, and now I have realized that when I want to zoom into an object, it gets really slow well before I reach the object's surface.

Is there a way to adjust the zoom and also panning when you have a super small scale set on?

Comment: Is it related to center of the rotation - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point ?

Comment: Pressing `Home` (*View → View All*) in *Object Mode* has solved it for me.  This and other solutions: [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39875/27483).

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be resolved by changing your blender preferences.

[Edit] > | Preferences... | -> | Navigation | > "Orbit & Pan" > "Auto", Under "Perspective", check "Depth" (At least on Blender 2.93)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is very old, but what I do is if I want to work up close, I switch to object mode, deselect everything, zoom in about where I want to be, then go back into edit mode. The zoom scale is reset from that point. So basically, the zoom scale will always be there, but wherever it starts is wherever you go into edit mode with nothing selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the object then press  <kbd>/</kbd> and it should zoom in to the center of the object