# How can I prevent the occasional Zoom In / Panning from breaking?

Tags: 3d-view, object-mode

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but occasionally (usually in `Object Mode`) while I'm `Zooming In` or `Panning` (using `Shift + Middle Mouse Button`), `Zooming In` will stop and won't allow me to zoom in any further (I can still zoom out, but can only zoom in so much), or `Panning` will no longer work.

I don't believe I've pressed any key combination to trigger this, as this usually happens during a time of me zooming or panning.

I did some research and found this question here *(which is similar to my issue)*:

- [Panning with Shift + middle mouse button stopped working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/panning-with-shift-middle-mouse-button-stopped-working)

But unfortunately, **"Restoring to Factory Defaults"** is in no means a proper answer for fixing something that feels more like a bug. (Especially if no settings/preferences were changed prior to this issue happening.) What does fix this issue is [@GilesDMiddleton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/17972/gilesdmiddleton)'s answer to go to `Object Mode` & click `View All` (Home button, if you have it).

- [@GilesDMiddleton's answer found here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39875/33751)

This is a good answer for quickly fixing this issue (while keeping all of your settings), but it's an odd fix and doesn't explain what causes the occasional (and sudden) "lock".

**Now back to my main question:**

How can I prevent this "bug/issue" from happening?

Or perhaps my question should be: What can cause the "Zoom In" & "Pan" to stop working, and why does `Object Mode` + `View All` fix the issue?

---

**Blender Version:** 2.78

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the 3d view clipping distance?

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point