# Shift + Midddle Mouse (Pan) and Numpad Not Working in 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am using Windows 10 an downloaded Blender 2.8.

The Shift + Middle Mouse does not pan and the Number Pad does not work.

I have tried all the proposed solutions here: [Panning with Shift + middle mouse button stopped working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2326/66867)

My Middle Mouse works fine for Rotate and Zoom.

I have tried replacing the keyboard and mouse, but no luck!

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Blender 2.8 twice, but no luck!

Thank you in advance....I can't wait to start using 2.8!

Comment: Same behaviour in Ubuntu 18.04; works in 2.79 though.

Comment: Just found solution that works for me: go to *Preferences > Input* and tick *Emulate Numpad*.