# My camera won't zoom after it reach certain distance of zoom

Tags: camera

My camera will not let me zoom in anymore after I zoom in on a huge obj. I know it is probably designed that way so we can zoom in anymore after certain amount,but I want to know if I can break that. I really need to zoom in more.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/644/12

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting "5" on you numeric keypad. It will switch to orthographic view mode. If that is not what you want try reading the thread iKlsR mentioned.

Comment: its still don't work