# problem zooming in inside geometry

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I am having a problem with Blender since I started using it: when I have a solid object (for example a cube) I cannot zoom in **inside** the surface; when I zoom in after the zoom reaches the surface it continues zooming in into the surface, but it never penetrates it. The only way to see inside the geometry is placing the camera inside and select the camera view. This problem happens equally in object and edit mode.

Please note that my problem is not that the zoom cannot get any further, but rather that I cannot penetrate to enter the inside of a closed solid (like a cube). This is something very common, particularly in architectural design, where you often start with a cube and the scene happens inside the cube.

Of course this problem is in no way a deal breaker for I can always place the camera in the right position and view through it, but that is rather limiting for I cannot get any other angle of the interior of my geometry than the camera angle; and besides it would be handy to be able to zoom in into the geometry before I set any camera; even to navigate to the adequate view and then set camera to view. I know this is possible for I see all the time in tutorials as a thing so basic that no explanation is required.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Sept

Comment: Hi ideasman42, I had already seen that post; but that is not my problem; the posting you referred to has problems being able to zoom to a point; however my problem is that I cannot penetrate a solid geometry; for example, if I have a cube which is a room, I would like to be able to zoom inside the geometry. This is what I cannot do. Sorry I did not explain myself properly in the original post.

Comment: Are you in ortho view? You can only zoom inside an object while in perspective view. To get this effect in ortho view, try inverting the normals and enabling backface culling.

Comment: @ideasman42 I don't think that question is what Sangreelah is asking.  I think the problem is, as gandalf3 said, that he is in ortho view instead of perspective.

Comment: @PGmath, I see the confusion, marked as a different, This question may also be useful - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644

Comment: Yes, the problem was I was in Ortho mode. Thank you for all your help.