# Change the scale of the viewport

Tags: modeling

I'm building a model that's very small, about a square millimeter, that I intend to have 3d printed. I've figured out the model at normal blender dimensions, with the units set to "None", and then I just set my units to "Metric" and scaled the thing down considerably.

Although I could use this model, I might want to make further changes, but since it's so small, it's difficult to work with since the viewport panning is messed up so closely zoomed.

How do I change the scale of my viewport from "meters" to something smaller, like "milimeters"? I've googled around and only find unrelated information.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate my problem.

[image]

Notice how in the top left corner of the viewport it says "User Persp" with "Meters" under it. I suspect that's what has to change.

Comment: The viewport controls don't behave any differently at different scales AFAIK, I suspect you are encountering [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/644/599). Try selecting your object and pressing `numpad .`, then see if the view navigation feels more natural.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise not infinitely. you can zoom about to 1/1000 (milimeter size), 1um (micro) is the smallest thing i could see or model/scale.

Comment: Note that in Orthographic views you will be able to snap to a much smaller grid (depending on your zoom).

Comment: @blaineh don't worry too much about that, scale your object to be able to do what you need. 3D printing sofwares can handle scaling before printing. Or edit your object and scale it when you're done in blender.

Comment: @blaineh "meters" or "feet" in the top left corner of the viewport is about the unit your using, not the scale. It should say metric or imperial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the scale of the whole scene to metric .001 (one thousandth of a meter=1mm).

Version 2.8X
[image]

Version 2.7X
[image]

But to be able to work at such small scale you also have to adjust the scale on the viewport as well:

For 2.8X The settings are in the overlay section.
[image]

For 2.7X they are in the Numeric Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>)
[image]

Here's what a 1mm x 1mm x 1mm object looks like in with such scaling:
[image]

Comment: The scene falls behind the viewport camera at very small sizes in "user perspective". Switch to orthographic to render the scene across the entire viewport. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86969/how-do-i-change-the-mode-of-perspective

Answer (score 4):

Just work in standard Blender units and pretend they are millimeters. When uploading your model to the 3D printing service you should be able to select that one Blender unit equals one millimeter!

Comment: Although this is a good answer, the other one is more technically correct and will help people in the future. This is what I've pretty much ended up doing though :)

Comment: Completly correct....but the answer was not there, when I added the comment ;)
Where can I find the same settings in Blender 2.8?