# Center viewport key in Blender breaks the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I set the key layout to Maya's to work faster, everything goes great.

But when using F key (i don't remember which one is in blender, but the center viewport position and rotation to selected object).

Then everything goes wrong. I'm not able to get near the object. The position where the camera gets centered is another , far from the object. Their pivot point is where i want to look, but the vew goes away, and moving is a nightmare.

Moreover, when trying to approach the object i wanted to center on, the camera gets slower and slower (as in Maya) but I'm not able to get there...

Is there a bug or something? What do you suggest me todo, instead? but not turning to blender layout, please. :-)

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, one of which I think is answered here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point .

Comment: press A to select all objects in your scene, then press numpad period.

Comment: X-27, this is not like that in Maya layout.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem like this early on.  It's because you're in perspective instead of ortho mode and in perspective the viewport behaves differently, it never goes in close to the object you're zooming, in ortho mode this doesn't happen.  Perhaps I'm over simplifying; but it behaves as you're saying on the 'when I move closer, I don't get any closer" I don't know about Maya.  If this is the issue, simply hit the number '5' on the number keypad in Blender key layout to switch between Ortho and Perspective, you want Ortho. if User Preferences are organized the same in Maya as in Blender, this would be under user settings: Input/3D View/3D View (Global)/View Persp/Ortho if you need to change user settings for Maya, or see what they are.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: Nope. That's not the problem, but useful though  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I tried to change to "walk mode" , which turns camera to a FPS game - like movement style. It said I couldn't change because my cam was locked to an object.

In fact, it was locked to the camera, so no matter where I centered the view, anything i did made it go towards that camera. So when using the wheel, it didn't go forward... but to the side (??) : It was moving towards the camera to which the view was locked to.

Funny. I did that while trying to move the camera together with the view... forgot to turn it off again :-D