# Navigation is completely not working

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I was using blender and I created a little character and when it came to putting it in pose mode so I could begin to animate it, from then on the navigation around the 3D window will not work it will zoom in and out but the only way for me to navigate now is through the View menu and this obviously takes forever and I can't get the angles I want, could I have pressed something to make it this way? I just generally cannot navigate at all around my interface.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: Make sure in the navigator window (N) you dont have the camera locked to target.

Answer (score 1):

I find when I have navigation problems, selecting a mesh and pressing the <kbd>.</kbd> key on the numpad fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I found going to *View > Frame All* will get the Hand and Zoom tool working again.