# Unable to move in viewport

Tags: 3d-view

So I encountered a problem when navigating in the 3D view in Blender. Somehow I am not able to move anywhere. I can rotate my view, but I cannot scroll/move horizontal or vertical. In other projects I am able to move normally.

Comment: See if this is related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have zoomed in too far? Try selecting an object in your scene and hitting "." on the num pad to recenter the view port on that object. Hope this helps.

Comment: This has happened to me before, so it most likely will work!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which centers your view and 3D cursor to the world center: `X,Y,Z = 0,0,0.`