# Cinema 4D style navigation

Tags: customization

I was using Blender with Maya configuration preset and it worked great for me, but since in 99% of Blender tutorials people are teaching using default configuration preset I've decided to switch on it.

I've bumped into a few annoying things:

- Using Maya preset I could press the <kbd>F</kbd> key to focus on the selected *item*/*vertex*/*face* and zoom, pan, rotate around it. In Blender preset it's almost the same with the <kbd>Del</kbd> key, but I can zoom only using **mouse wheel** (which is extremely uncomfortably for me), if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> zoom, the focus resets.
- Sometimes I can't even zoom or pan properly, it starts behaving very slow so I have to refocus with the <kbd>F</kbd> on the different objects to reset this bug or whatever this is.

Is there a preset or an addon to make Blender behave like Cinema 4D. In Cinema 4D the focused *object*/*vertex*/*face* is always the one mouse is pointed at.

Comment: There's a such hotkey - `Alt`+`F` which lets you zoom to current mouse position and rotate / pan etc. around it. It works in every interaction mode except for the Edit mode. It's possible to use it on the fly without any user prefs changings.

Comment: You second bullet is a common problem present in pretty much any 3D software, it's explained quite nicely [in the question and answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution would be to

1. Go to user preference > Interface > View Manipulation ...
2. Turn off "Rotate Around Selection"
3. Turn on "Auto Depth", "Cursor Depth", "Zoom to Mouse Position".

Now when you zoom take care to place your mouse at the object where you want to zoom or rotate around. It will now no longer slow down zoom when you hit a threshold. Instead it will always trys to determine the depth relative to your mouse position to any 3d surface you point the mouse cursor at.

Rotate around Selection is deceiving ... it gives you the notion that you would be rotating around a selected element. In reality the tool only rotate around the element when you zoom to selected first. Moreover when you select your next object it will use the formal element's scene depth. This is ok for single element selection, it however proves ineffective when you need to select multiple objects which just happens to be far apart.