# Camera will not rotate around anything

Tags: camera

(User preferences->Rotate around selection on)

My camera in the view-port will not rotate or move, I can not rotate around my objects, and sometimes the grid will move too. I didn't save my blender file in this way before I closed my project, but it so happens to be in the state on opening. When I right click the grid moves in object mode, even in quad view I cant drag the objects view. Zoom in and out works. Middle mouse button does not work. I have tried:

- It's like this for a new blend file too
- view lock to object, lock camera view [x] & [ ]
- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>num</kbd>& <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>num</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
- <kbd>Space</kbd>->clear lock view (doesn't appear)

[image]

Comment: Cant you provide us a .blend file (you can upload it here 
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com
).

Comment: I can rotate around the viewport :/ and everything works normally :/ (Also note that you should add a camera to be able to render )

Comment: Im unable to, still its just static. I have no idea about adding a camera. Can you do remote control and fix it for me at my end. Im getting frustrated

Comment: Take a break i'll try to post an answer in about 10 minutes.

Comment: I solved it, somehow in my user preferences rotate around selection was not ticked :/ Cheers though! I'll add a camera too!

Comment: Glad you found it ;)

Comment: Could you write an answer and accept it? Don't put the answer in your question. If you have an answer just write an answer and accept it because unaccepted/unanswered questions draw more attention to them.

Comment: I wrote it above. How do I accept it.

Comment: @Pyratae to write an answer please use the answer section, do not write the answer as part of the question. Once you have an answer you'll be able to accept it using the check mark.

Comment: It's not clear which camera did you mean - 3d viewport point of view or camera to be used for rendering. Your file does not contain the latter and can be panned with MMB just fine. Probably this could be related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point. I should also mention that Rotate Around Selection isn't necessary for panning / rotating the view in 3d viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User preferences rotate around selection needs to be ticked.