# viewport lags and won't move

Tags: 3d-view, scene

When I am working in a scene sometimes the view on the viewport just won't zoom in, and I can't pan, only rotate the view...

Comment: Which camera do you mean and how does it happen that you can pan view but can't rotate, can you elaborate? If viewport camera is meant then see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: I mean the camera that is the viewport. When I have a long object and I need to get to the end of my object (Viewport). After some zooming in the camera (Viewport) just stops and wouldn't let me zoom in nor pan the view, I can only rotate the view. But I found a way: I just select some faces the press "View to selected".