# How to change the scroll distance

Tags: scene

If I scroll the mouse one time then it goes very far:

[image]
[image]

It is hard to work like this and not normal behaviour. If I start a new project then everything is ok. Im not sure what I did, how can I change it back to normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing center point the viewport is orbitting around; as ab alternative you can change the Pivot point to *Median Point* or *Bounding Box* (as it looks like you have it set to something other than *Median Point*), still the latter might not be the best solution.

This seems to be caused by the fact that you zoomed in and out too much around the scene in different orientations and created big offset between the location of current central point and location of the actual viewport camera.

This behaviour also depends on setup iin User Preferences you use, like *Auto Depth*, *Zoom to Mouse Position*, *Rotate Around Selection* and locks to object or cursor on the Properties shelf.

One easy method would be to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and draw a rectangle where you want new center to be (note that there should be any geometry to draw on though as otherwise depth of field will be too large). From this point of view this question is related to [Why does the zoom sometimes stop at a point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point), there also are several ways to reset the center point.

Comment: It works again after using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and draw the rectangle on my model!

Answer (score 1):

As we know, the scrolling zoom speed increases with the distance from the center point of the viewport camera. I think the problem occurs because the center point is far away from view.

**I suggest**:

1)Select the object and press <kbd>NUM .</kbd> to move center point to the selection.

2)Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> to perform **precise zooming**.

3)Use **fly mode** (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) to navigate.

Comment: Yes but it seems that this behaviour is specific to the scene @Black is working on.

Comment: I know that I could use CTRL+Middle Click, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: Alright, looks like I'm too late with my edit.