# What if panning and zooming isn't working

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but occasionally (usually in Object Mode) while I'm Zooming In or Panning (using Shift + Middle Mouse Button), Zooming In will stop and won't allow me to zoom in any further (I can still zoom out, but can only zoom in so much), or Panning will no longer work.

I don't believe I've pressed any key combination to trigger this, as this usually happens during a time of me zooming or panning.

I did some research and found this question here (which is similar to my issue):

Panning with Shift + middle mouse button stopped working
But unfortunately, "Restoring to Factory Defaults" is in no means a proper answer for fixing something that feels more like a bug. (Especially if no settings/preferences were changed prior to this issue happening.) What does fix this issue is @GilesDMiddleton's answer to go to Object Mode & click View All (Home button, if you have it).

@GilesDMiddleton's answer found here
This is a good answer for quickly fixing this issue (while keeping all of your settings), but it's an odd fix and doesn't explain what causes the occasional (and sudden) "lock".

Now back to my main question:

How can I prevent this "bug/issue" from happening?

Or perhaps my question should be: What can cause the "Zoom In" & "Pan" to stop working, and why does Object Mode + View All fix the issue?

Comment: Looks the same as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point