# How to reset viewpoint settings

Tags: 3d-view

The problem is that my viewpoint settings have become wonky as when I zoom I will end up in random places and when rotating it will start dramatically change what I am seeing one thing then it disappears and reappears somewhere else. Blender version is 2.79

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting one thing, then press the <kbd>Number Pad Period</kbd> key (to activate ***View Selected***).  That'll reset the focus to what you had selected (and zoom you in on it). Then your navigation in the viewport should be more controllable again.

Comment: I have tried see the video [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfxiWNqOK3Z0zKuCcnOenCU_DrbFf-Je/view?usp=sharing) when rotating it is not consistent.

Comment: In the video, you seem to be rendering. You shouldn't be both navigating in the viewport, and rendering at the same time.

Comment: I was rendering a different scene but even when not rendering it's a issue.

Comment: I think you need to upload your file then so people can find out what's going on. (But I'm off to bed now, so won't see it for some hours.)

Comment: Here is the link it is the same folder as the video [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mIM59zCz155qbXkCI86pcykVzfkVc6_U?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I press 1 on the number pad to come into Front View, and then start to navigate so it comes into User view, then make sure it's set to Perspective, not Ortho, (5) then the navigation keys work as I'd expect.  Your scene is so big that I think a tiny movement of the mouse jerks the scene a lot further than you want.  You can press Shift while you rotate the scene to slow the action down.  I think the main thing that helps reset, is pressing a Number Pad key, 1, 3, or 7 to get into one of those views.  The Home key also helps get everything more centered on the screen.

Comment: Put simply make sure your in perspective mode select a object to rotate around and press delete on the number pad.Also thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have the center of your view locked to Bullet 001. If you click on the x beside the name field, the navigation is suddenly "normal".