# How can ı fix this? "when ı approach the object,camera is slowing"

Tags: modeling, texturing

How can ı fix this?  "when ı approach the object,camera is slowing"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXK3M.jpg (Sorry i didnt upload the example video to this website)

Comment: Hi mcanince. This is a frequently asked question, see: [Why does the zoom sometimes stop at a point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point)

Answer (score 0):

Thats just for precision purpose,but u can "reset it" just selecting the object in question,and pressing Numpad .  ("point").That will zoom on it and should fix the problem