# Zoom is not working properly

Tags: objects

Sometimes, right in the middle of a project, when I'm trying to zoom in on an object, the zoom just halts at a certain point as if I'm reached some kind of limit, even though I earlier was able to go much closer. What is the deal with this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point/651

Comment: Ah, yes! Auto depth solved it. Thanks a bunch.