# Is it possible to change power of zoom in /out in viewport with respect to distance from active object

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface

I have a problem with zooming in while modeling small details on my meshes as blender decreases my zooming power when I am close to my mesh this also happens sometimes when I decrease scale of a large object
I am unable to go further closer to the mesh from particular distance from the mesh

Comment: Read this link: [Why does the zoom sometimes stop at a point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point)

Answer (score 0):

When zooming in blender, the viewport camera will move closer to its centre of rotation. You can move the centre of rotation by panning (holding shift and the middle mouse button), or the easier way would probably be to press the decimal key on your numpad to centre the camera on the selected object.