# Why Can't I Zoom or Slide any more in the Viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

This happens to me from time to time and I can't understand it.  There is this invisible boundary I hit where the viewport will no longer zoom in, and I also seem to be stuck in side to side/up and down motion.

I can rotate just fine, but I can't move in the other dimensions unless I zoom back out, which is sluggish but then suddenly comes back alive once I get out of the weird dead zone.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/czmp4ifs15hj3u1/Zoom%20Why.blend?dl=0)

If someone could have a look at my project file and let me know what I'm missing, or if this happens on your machine, I'd be most grateful!

[image]

EDIT:

I am re-opening this question because, even though a similar question was posted with many attempted answers, none of those answers is apropos in my case.

For the following reasons:

1. I am not at the center of the scene.
2. I have not reached a point where further magnification is not possible (if I hit / to isolate an object the viewport zoomes in further to that object).
3. I am not inside of an object.
4. I have tried enabling/disabling all of the viewport options in the Preferences, including orbit around object, etc.

It seems as though, as others have pointed out in that thread, that there is some glitch or setting that clamps the view at a certain point, and I am totally at a loss as to what that could be.

Ideally starting this new thread on the topic might shed some new light on the subject as that thread has apparently already had an answer that is satisfactory to the question- but in this particular case does not apply.

EDIT 2:

My question keeps getting closed but I am once again re-opening it because the other associated question does not address this.  In the attached project file you will see that the viewport can not zoom into the cube (shown in the screenshot) any further past this point.  However, the view is quite far from the cube.

None of the suggestions in the other thread that my question keeps get associating with are relevant to this question, so please whoever keeps closing this question, stop doing that, and let's see if maybe we can find a solution to an issue that is not the same.

EDIT 3:

Why does this question keep getting closed? I am genuinely hoping someone can open this project file and let me know what is going on, and why the viewport is unable to zoom (without a workaround, that is).

Yes, I understand that someone has asked a *similar* question.  But none of the answers, which are all workarounds, or explanations are relevant to my situation.  Please keep this question open until there is a suitable answer, per the attached project file.  Thank you.

Comment: Hello, maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: Thanks @moonboots I have read through that whole thread.  In fact, I did so before posting my question.  But none of those answers seems to be acceptable in my case as I am definitely not zoomed in to a point where further magnification is not possible, nor am I at the center of the scene, or inside of an object.  It appears, at the very least, that it may be a bug in my event.  I was hoping that someone could open up that project file and let me know if they experience the same thing.

Comment: Hello glen, it's not that the camera couldn't move, it's that you've reached the view plane you're currently viewing the scene from (also the point your camera orbits around)  Select an object and use numpad . (decimal character) to center the view plane on that object.

Comment: Hi @AllenSimpson thanks for checking.  Did you open the project file and that's how you came to this conclusion?  Because for me that isn't my experience at all.  No matter what objects I have in the scene, this is the furthest point I can reach.  Which is quite macro, as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: Why *View > Frame Selected* (key *Numpad_dot*) doesn't work for you? It's probably a glitch. What do you expect? You also can focus on the 3D Cursor if you check the *Lock to 3D Cursor* checkbox in the N-panel > *View tab > View Lock*.

Comment: I downloaded your file and your issue is the same as in the linked thread, the solution there worked in your file

Comment: Hey @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for looking. Which solution are you referring?  The only "solution" I see that works are workarounds that go against the basic function of the viewport (i.e. isolating the object, doing a dolly move, etc).  But as far as just being able to normally zoom the viewport, I did not find a solution there that works. Please enlighten me ;)

Comment: Hey @Blunder, what I expect is to be able to zoom in the viewport normally, without having to use any kind of workaround (which is disruptive to my natural flow).  In this particular case (the project file attached) I am unable to do so.

Comment: @glen_candle https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/navigation.html - perhaps Auto Depth and Zoom to Mouse Position are what you're looking for

Comment: @glen_candle What is the first solution presented by ideasman42 in his paragraph titled **Solutions**?