# Why can't I zoom in further, and why doesn't applying the scale work?

Tags: transforms

I'm a total noob and following [this beginners tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imdYIdv8F4w&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=2). My aim is developing some smooth models to print in my 3D-printer (which is impossible with Tinkercad which I've been using up until now). At [this point in the tutorial](https://youtu.be/imdYIdv8F4w?t=443) he says I need to "*apply the scale*" and he shows how I should do it. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I recorded a short screencast to show what's happening here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T25aDFLxuhc

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Why can't I apply the scale and why can't I zoom in further?

Comment: It didn't work because the object wasn't selected...

Comment: for the zoom question, maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: ..and to add to what @AlexandreMarcati said, the object wasn't selected (as you can see on the missing orange outline) and you might wonder why the scale values are shown: the properties show the values of the last selected object until you select a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that torus is currently the active object (you're operating on it) but it's not selected in the viewport.  Things can be the active object, but no longer selected, if that makes sense.  Click on it and it should get the orange outline that means it's selected, and then <kbd>Ctrl + <kbd>A</kbd></kbd> -> *Apply Scale* should work.

As for the viewport zoom, you had moved the view around at some time in the past and now you've zoomed all the way in to the view plane.  When your object is selected you can press Numpad <kbd>.</kbd> to center view on the torus.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!