# Changing the step size in zoom and move view

Tags: 3d-view

I am using the buttons "Zoom in/out in the view" and "Move the view" often, but encounter an error/bug.

The scale/step size on which I am moving/zoom changes without any conscious choice.
I am moving around in the scene and all of a sudden, the step size changes to minimal such that I am hardly moving at all.

1. Where do I change the step size?
2. Why does it change automatically?

This also affects the **Dolly mode** discussed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point).

So far, I have to restart Blender all the time.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no way to change the 'step size' of the viewport zoom. Honestly, i would recommend using a mouse with a wheel (*Middleclick-Drag* lets you Orbit the camera, *Shift+Middleclick-Drag* is for panning, *Ctrl+Middleclick-Drag* is for smooth zooming).

Then you can try to improve Blenders behavior: Enable Prefences > Navigation > Auto Depth, so Blenders zooming will depend on what your mouse is pointing to.
[image]

But even without a mouse, there are some possible life-savers:
You can try *View > Frame All* if you get lost. To jump to a specific object, hit *View > Frame Selected*
[image]

As a last resort, you can alway reset View and 3D Cursor positions to *'center all'* with Shift+C.