# Why can't I zoom into my viewport so suddenly?

Tags: 3d-view

When I start Blender (3.2.2), I suddenly can't zoom with the mouse wheel in object mode, but everything works normally in Edit, Sculpt and other modes. This problem occurred after I installed addons.

But even after deleting the addons and using "Load Factory Settings" the problem persists. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it the same question as here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: @moonboots , Ah yes! Thanks much! It was a big help!