How to adjust scale of workspace to fit models?
I just adjusted the scale of my objects in Scene Properties > Unit Scale > Centimeters, but now my workspace is really tiny.
I have to be uncomfortably zoomed in. Is there  a way to adjust?
Here's a new cube next to it for comparison.



Hello and welcome to BSE. You scaled the object to be tiny. Why did you scale it that small in the first place? Setting Unit Length to Centimeters doesn't change anything fundamentally in the workspace. You just see measurements in cm instead of m so any added cube is now 200cm x 200cm instead of 2m x 2m. Your tiny cube is just scaled smaller maybe 10cm now since you scaled it that small. Remember 1m = 100cm. For zooming problems you can consult this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

that was my understanding. but they weren't this small before i changed the scale!
is there a way for me to physically scale them up but then still read the measurements in cm? and as 1.6cm, not 106cm

as for the reason they are so small is because they're dice that in real life scaling would be eg. 1.6cm.

i've tried to self adjust it - i scaled them up 100%, and then re-adjusted the unit scale from 0.01 to 0.001 so that it would read 1.6cm instead of 16cm but it made the models "tiny" again. is there a way to just view them better than how they are then?

If you want your workspace (and I guess you mean especially the grid in this case) to match your objects when you are working with them in the centimeters range instead of meters, you have to understand what the settings do.
Let's begin with the default scene which comes with Blender. The Unit System is set to Metric and the standard display unit for Length is Meters. Then there is the default cube and by default its dimensions are 2 m × 2 m × 2 m, as all default primitive objects usually have a bounding box of that size, based off of a unit sphere with a radius of 1 m, resulting in a diameter of 2 m, apart from the 2-dimensional plane and the circle as well as the torus, which is basically a profile sweeped around the circle.

Now when you change the display unit for the Length from Meters, nothing actually changes only that the dimensions of the cube will no longer be shown in meters, but centimeters. Also every new primitive object that you add to the scene will still have its default size of 2 m in XYZ, only that it shows as 200 cm.

So when you are creating objects that are 1.6 cm, they are still tiny compared to newly added objects and the grid background. And you would have to scale the new objects down to fit to your small objects. To change that, you have the Unit Scale setting in the Scene Properties. By changing this to 0.01 (as you already have as I can see in your screenshot) you tell Blender, you want every measurement to be just 1/100th of the original size. Which means, the default dimensions of objects are no longer 2 m, but 2 cm. Also added new objects will be 2 cm in size. Just by changing the scale, the cube is now no longer 200 cm, but 200 cm / 100 = 2 cm in size. But the cube itself is not scaled down, the camera and light in the scene still look the same relative to the cube - because you are scaling the units, not the objects.

The only thing which makes it look tiny now is the grid. The grid in the viewport is way too large for the objects - that is because the Viewport Overlays have their own Scale setting. When you change the Unit Scale of the scene to 0.01, the Scale for the grid display does not change automatically with it, it is still at 1. So change the Scale in the overlays to 0.01 to match the grid to the scaled down scene units.


thank you so much! just the answer i needed ahaha

@BeetleRolling If this helped you, please consider accepting the answer: What should I do when someone answers my question?
