# List of hot Keys for Mac Mini. OS X10.6.8

Tags: shortcut

Having issues following the tutorial because the hot keys and short cuts are not working for me. If I click my spinwheel it won't allow me to orbit my 3D View instead it toggle windows on my computer.
Toggle full screen Alt F10- doesn't work
Toggle Quad View doesn't work, etc....

I am a novice attempting to learn Blender but it just makes it more difficult not being able to follow the tutorial.

Comment: AFAIK most (all?) the hot keys are consistent across platforms. You can view/search/change them in *File > User preferences > Input*, but it sounds like you might be better off disabling the conflicting shortcuts in your OS (unless you use those features).

Comment: (Adding to @gandalf3 comment) If your operating system is using the same keyboard shortcuts they take precedence over blender's commands.

Comment: @gandalf3 All the keys are consistent. The os shortcuts take precedence as cegaton says. On ubuntu, common ones are `Ctrl Alt 0` and `Alt RMB`. It's preferred to change the os shortcuts so Blender's own stay consistent. You can start here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse, the recommended tool to use is [keyremap4macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).