# How do I emulate the Home key on a mac laptop in Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am trying to set the camera to the viewport on a mac laptop.  I use View>Align View>Align Active Camera To View.
This gives me the view but the camera is too zoomed in.  From looking on the stack exchange I believe if I press the Home key this will give me what I want.  How can I do this on my macbook pro keyboard ?

Comment: Already answered here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse

Comment: @MargretStorm No, it isn't that post is about the Number Pad, not the Home Key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Home command, press down the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

Home : <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> (Works exactly similar to Windows Home key)

End : <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Page Up : <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>

Page Down : <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

Essentially, all the buttons that would normally appear above the arrows on a  windows keyboard, are mimicked by using arrow keys with modifiers.

I don't know why the other answers are talking about un-related number pad, which is another key group entirely.

Comment: I believe HOME is just fn+Left Cursor, and END is fn+Right Cursor. No need to press CTRL (source: http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/17/home-end-button-mac-keyboard-functions/)

Comment: This must be out of date I suppose. None of these key combinations do anything, except for one of them, which opened up a bunch of console windows and such, which I'm now unable to close.

Comment: no, it is NOT out of date. Fn + Leftarrow works.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, or maybe <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

To emulate the Numpad, go to:
*File > User Preferences > Input > Emulate Numpad*.

It should be about half way down in the left.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the Home key