# Basic Interface 2.8: How do I get Shader nodes in view to be centered and large on first click?

Tags: interface, shaders

I have a project with multiple objects.  I work on the project for a while, save it, quit blender, reopen it etc.  I click on an object in the viewport and open the Shader view and cannot see my shader nodes.  I have to scroll out until I see my tiny node setup, then I have to center it and zoom in.  Is there some simple basic way to tell blender to open the shader nodes so that they generally use available visible real estate by default?  It's a small issue but irritating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to put all the nodes in view, press the period key on the keypad to center on a selected node.

Also, if you're on a mac, you might check this: [How do I emulate the Home key on a mac laptop in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52430/how-do-i-emulate-the-home-key-on-a-mac-laptop-in-blender)