# 2019 Macbook Pro (laptop) keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, osx

I'm UI graphic designer and junior front end dev and I started learning blender few days ago but everytime I open blender and trying to do something while watching tutorials I'm stuck in the keyboard shortcuts issues. I find so many shortcuts links but for the Windows. I feel like Mac is something "special" for this.
I will really happy if someone can help me, or if someone has any tips.

Thanks a lot! O:)

Comment: You mean shortcuts *IN* Blender or for the Mac?

Comment: Shortcuts for Blender but for Mac, not for Windows. It's different, unfortunately. When I'm using windows shortcuts in blender on mac usually works nothing.

Comment: I used to use Mac, and it worked fine for me. Are you sure that you have shortcuts enabled? I don't know if you can disable it, but there might be a function that does something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems when starting with Blender (I'm using a MacBook without mouse and Blender 2.80). Here some tipps:

- most shortcuts are made for people with a numpad, if you only have a simple keyboard, you can change it under Edit -> Preferences -> Input -> Keyboard -> check "Emulate Numpad" (here's an older post about this topic [How to emulate a Number Pad and 3 Button Mouse?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse))

[image: go to preferences]
[image: check Emulate Numpad]

- I also changed some of the Hotkeys under Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap (a lot of Hotkeys use keys I don't have on my simple laptop keyboard, so you might want to switch some of the functions you are using most often to key-combinations you have and are still available). **It's also useful to browse trough and lookup Hotkey combinations here (they should be specific for mac and not windows)**
  After you changed a hotkey, it has an arrow pointing left besides it (in blender 2.80) For example I changed the "view selected" to Alt+Q

[image: Changed keymap for view selected]

- Another important thing is to choose how you want to select stuff (either right or left mouse click), you'll also find it under Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap -> 3D View -> Mesh -> 3DView: Tool Select (earlier versions of Blender had a more global switch for that)

[image: right or left click]

I hope this helps, let me know if you have questions (also always post the blender version you are using with your question, because Blender changed a lot in the last months)

Comment: Hey guys, thank you very much. I didnt have disabled hotkeys I mean shortcuts. I just reinstall blender few times and everything looks fine for this time. Anyway, thanks <3 

I just need to make some shortcuts of mine.