# need help with camera placement?

Tags: modeling, rendering, camera

i need help i am using blender on a macbook pro and i have finished a model, i have an angle placed and need to use the camera to render it. I can not manually use the camera otherwise i will lose my good angle and it will be a pain in the ass. i know i can use ctl-alt-0 and commant-alt-0 but it simple does nothing i can not even access my camera through pressing 0. i dont know what is the problem, do i need to edit something? activate something? i need advise on how to fix this.

Comment: I've never used a Mac, but does your Mac actually **have** a numpad? - Using the '0' key on the top row of the keyboard won't work. See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse) posting.

Comment: If you're using a MacBook Pro with a keyboard that has a numpad, make sure that the Num Lock is set.  see [this support note](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-a-numeric-keypad-doesnt-work-mchlp2366/mac) for other possible reasons why it's not working.

Comment: OK, that fixed it thanks. needed to emulate the number pad. about time this got fixed, trying to find the answer was a real pain.